# WS-Security on iphone, is it possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ws-security

I'm new here and I'm facing a problem. I need to know if it is possible to implement the WS-Security protocol with X.509 certificates on a native iPhone application. I haven't found much information on the web, except this [information from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/Security_Overview/Security_Services/Security_Services.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000976-CH204-CHDFGEIH) about security services.

I just want to ask, is it possible? has it been made before?. If it is possible, can you point me in the right direction?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to implement this using OpenSSL.

There is a tutorial on [The Rare AiR](http://www.therareair.com/2009/01/01/tutorial-how-to-compile-openssl-for-the-iphone/) on how you can compile the library for iPhone.

Hope this helps,
Claus

Comment: Thanks, it seems that I can create encrypted connections with Apple's CFNetwork API. I think the complicated part of this will be creating the soap headers that WS-Security requires.

Comment: You could also have a look at the Security.framework. It should offer you some options for doing X.509 certificates as well in addition to a few types of encryption, but nowhere nearly as full fledged as OpenSSL

Comment: Thank you very much, I haven't found answers anywhere else. I will probably give OpenSSL a try.